# Spring MessageSource into Service

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i  have a problem with using MessageSource to read properties if I put this last outside the controller but inside a service like this:

```
@Service
public class MessageHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private static MessageSource messageSource;

    public static void returnMessage(String key, Locale locale) {
        logger.info(key);
        logger.info(locale.toString());
        logger.info(messageSource.getMessage(key, null, locale));
    }

}
```

This service is located in: com.test.rest.utility

the servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:properties/welcome" />
        <beans:property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />  
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>


    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.test.rest.dao.UserDaoImpl" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.rest.utility" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.rest.controller" />



</beans:beans>
```

the controller where I go to call the service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody  List<Project> home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        String key = "message";
        MessageHandler.returnMessage(key, locale);
}
```

the application return me a NullPointerException when into the service call messageSource.getMessage(key, null, locale)

can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `<context:component-scan base-package="package where services is located"/>` to scan your service and configure it as a spring bean then it will be available for other beans

Comment: if you check well the known xml code I entered:
`<context: component-scan base-package = "com.test.rest.utility" />`
here is the service

Comment: sorry, in fact you cannot autowire static filed in spring change  autowire on static method

Comment: I also tried not to use it as a static type but the result is always that

Comment: did you inject it in your controller?

Comment: oh thank you very much, I solved by creating an interface for the service and made to implement the service and in the controller I added the service injected. Only now I have another doubt. I wanted to do it static in such a way as to use it in all the controllers without injecting the service every time. It's possible?

Comment: make your MessageHandler implements ApplicationContextAware mark the field applicationContext as a static filed and retrieve your MessageSource from that applicatincontext without inject t by autowiring and use it in your returnMessage method

Comment: Similiar to this [link](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_applicationcontextaware_spring)  ? @biiyamn

Comment: yes , but mark the applicationContext as static field

Answer (score 1):

You cannot autowire static filed. So you can:

- Create an interface: MessageService
- Implement MessageService into MessageHandler
- Inject the service with:

  ```
          private MessageService service;

          @Autowired
          public void setMessageService(MessageService service){
               this.service = service;
          }
           ....
          service.returnMessage(key,null, locale)
  ```